# Understanding render mix ratios

Tags: render

So if i have 8 sand & 1 cement, is this a shovel full or bag? i've got a small area to render with a pigment mixed with Snowcrete and don't want to be using more than i need.

Comment: Ratios are independent of units, whether you're baking cookies or mixing concrete. You decide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its an 8:1 ratio, it can be bags, cups, shovels, whatever measure you use as along as its 8 parts sand to 1 part cement. The area your looking to fill is it small where your measure will be cups or larger were you would use shovels. Once you know your unit of measure, you can use the right amount with little waste.